# Getting unauthorized after login in spring boot reactive

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to create form login with spring boot webflux. I can login and after login I'm redirectored successfully. But when I browse to a page that requires authentication, I'm getting error. If I remove the page from security config and get principal from `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` I'm getting the user details.

Here is my security config:

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/user/account")
                    .authenticated()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user/login")
                    .authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/"))
                    .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager() {
        return authentication -> userService.loginUser(authentication)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new UsernameNotFoundException(authentication.getName())))
                .map(user -> new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null));
    }
}
```

Do I need to do anything else in the `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`? Is that even required?

Answer (score 0):

In this repository : https://github.com/mohamedanouarbencheikh/dashboard-auth-microservice
you have a complete example of spring security implementation with jwt in microservice architecture using spring cloud routing (gateway) which is based on reactive programming and Netty as application server, and angular as frontend

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question so that anyone facing same problem can get some help:

The issue was resolved when I've changed the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` constructor and passed the authority parameter as `null`. This is really ridiculous. Here is the updated code:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager() {
    return authentication -> userService.loginUser(authentication)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new UsernameNotFoundException(authentication.getName())))
            .map(user -> new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities()));
}
```

I've also simplified the config by removing `authenticationSuccessHandler` and `authenticationManager` from the config. Spring automatically redirects to `/`. For `authenticationManager` it automatically checks for a `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` bean and uses if found. Here is my updated config:

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/user/account")
                .authenticated()
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler("/user/bye"))
            .and()
            .build();
}
```